# how to setup an oracle 10 g linked server in sql server 2008 R2 (windows server 2008 R2) 64 bit

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, oracle10g, linked-server

I need to setup a linked server on my new sql 2008 R2 server but there is no oracle data provider in providers list of my server and when I'm trying to install oracle client or oracle data provider it's giving me an error saying doesn't support Operating system version 6.1 !!!
please tell me which driver do I have to install and where can I download it from ?
thanks

Comment: You need a 64-bit Data Provider for Oracle to be able to get it to work. I'm not aware of one off the top of my head.

Comment: that's what I'm looking for and trying to install !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I found the way how to do it which I would explain it here as I think other people may have this problem :

Use the correct and only certified install source from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/10204-winx64-vista-win2k8-082253.html)

Unpack and open a command prompt in the "..\database" directory where the "setup.exe" is located.
Run the following command: setup.exe -ignoreSysprereqs

Wait for the OUI windows and continue with your preferences selections.
When the OUI prerequisites window appear it will come with the following error:

INFO: The user has manually verified 'Checking operating system requirements ...'
INFO: Checking CertifiedVersions 
This is a prerequisite condition to test whether the Oracle software is certified on the current O/S.
INFO: Expected result: One of 5.0,5.1,5.2,6.0
Actual Result: 6.1
Check complete. The overall result of this check is: Failed <<<<

Select the checkbox to bypass the error and continue installation

and something else that you have to do before creating the linked server is :
go to sql server management studio
open server objects\linked servers\providers
right click on oraoledb.oracle and the properties
in properties check the box for Allow inprocess.

it's all ready now use oraoledb.oracle to create the linked server .